# Problems selecting Themes Using My Unity

Tags: installation, themes, home-directory, gnome-tweak-tool

This question may be subjective but I am having problems selecting GTK3 Themes using My Unity.

**Background**

Some GTK3 Theme installation instructions ask you place the extracted theme folder in **~/.Themes** *(hidden in your home folder)* and here is where the problem starts (for My Unity).  I have to use **Advanced Settings** (Gnome Tweak tool) to select themes from the home folder to get the theme working correctly.

When I review the selected Theme in **My Unity** it places a big red X beside the selected theme name.  Themes installed in ~/.Themes DO NOT work correctly when selected in **My Unity**

I resolved this by ignoring GTK3 installation instructions and copying the same theme folders to **usr/share/themes** using Sudo Nautilus. These themes work perfectly now when selected in My Unity.  Does anyone know why this behavior happens in My Unity (when themes are placed in ~/.Themes, and can it be fixed.  This is not machine specific as it happens on my daughters laptop as well.

Comment: shouldn't it be `~/.themes` and not `~/.Themes` since things are case-sensitive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you didn't say which user interface you use in Ubuntu: [Gnome Shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Shell) with GNOME 3 or Unity. I'd say that **MyUnity** is supposed to be used with Unity, not the Gnome Shell. On the other hand, the **Advanced Settings** (Gnome Tweak Tool) is supposed to work with Gnome Shell.

In [Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11988857) I've read that **GTK3 themes** should work well both with Unity and Gnome Shell. A theme package can be extracted to **~/.themes** directory, which means that it is accessible only by the current user, or to **/usr/share/themes** (you need admin rights for that), which is accessible by all users, but in both cases a theme should work the same.

The **red X** beside the theme name in MyUnity simply means that you can delete the theme (place the mouse pointer above the X to see a hint). It appears for themes installed in ~/.themes directory.